# Gerando arquivo CSV com Fast-csv no NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, csv

Preciso escrever um CSV com dados de um JSON, porém não consigo gerar o arquivo com os dados. Estou utilizando o fast-csv Package. Nenhum erro é informado durante a execução.

Segue meu código:

```
   async function generateCsv() {

   const fastcsv = require("fast-csv");
   const fs = require("fs");
   var path = "../csv/final_dataset.csv";
   const ws = fs.createWriteStream(path, { flags: "w" });

   db.query("SELECT * FROM distance", (error, result) => {

   const jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.rows));
   console.log(jsonData);

   fastcsv
  .write(jsonData, { headers: true, duplicates: false })
  .on("finish", function () {
    console.log("Write to csv successfully!");
  })
  .pipe(ws);
  });
  }

  module.exports = {
    generateCsv,
  };
```

Dados que pretendo escrever no CSV. Resultado do console.log(jsonData):

```
[
 { id: 1420, date: '2021-03-26', distance: '3.7889199999999996' },
 { id: 1421, date: '2021-03-25', distance: '3.6386399999999997' },
 { id: 1422, date: '2021-03-31', distance: '0.5502699999999999' },
 { id: 1423, date: '2021-04-01', distance: '0.97' },
 { id: 1424, date: '2021-03-29', distance: '0.5358499999999999' },
 { id: 1425, date: '2021-03-28', distance: '0.59277' },
 { id: 1432, date: '2021-04-04', distance: '0.58139' }
]
```

Ao executar esta função do exemplo, o arquivo CSV não é gerado com o conteúdo no caminho especificado. Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Olá Matheus. É importante **[edit]** e adicionar **um [mcve] do problema**, com um passo a passo do que já fez e explicar de forma clara e objetiva o que precisa. **Não delete e não repita a pergunta**, basta editar e aguardar o processo de reabertura. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Obrigado por compreender.